# Similarity algorithm for hierarchical structures

Tags: java, android, algorithm

There is a screen hierarchy in Android terms (in a text form).

The task is to get a "fingerprint" of a screen to recognize it later. The structure may change insignificant, so it's great to get similarity in percents.

Variety of containers/UI elements is limited (e.g. LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc.), so the order and hierarchy are important.

Are there any similarity algorithms for hierarchical structures? Or should I go for Strings similarity algorithms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of professors from Salzburg University have made a website about a similarity measure for trees called [Tree Edit Distance (TED)](http://tree-edit-distance.dbresearch.uni-salzburg.at/). The website includes information about, an implementation of and links to scientific literature about TED.

As a slightly simpler alternative, you could represent each of the hierarchical structures as a unique string and compute the [string edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) between the two representations.